# Trying to Capture Shapes in an image in openCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

i have the image shown below and i am attempting to just capture the Squares and place a green line around them any help or direction would be great.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('beef.png')
imgGry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret , thrash = cv2.threshold(imgGry, 240 , 255, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours , hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thrash, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for contour in contours:
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 0.01* cv2.arcLength(contour, True), True)
cv2.drawContours(img, [approx], 0, (0, 0, 0), 5)
x = approx.ravel()[0]
y = approx.ravel()[1] - 5
x, y , w, h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
aspectRatio = float(w)/h
print(aspectRatio)

if aspectRatio >= 0.95 and aspectRatio < 1.05:
cv2.putText(img, "square", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0))

else:
cv2.putText(img, "rectangle", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0))

cv2.imshow('shapes', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what your problem is (are the contours wrong? Nothing is being drawn on the image? etc) but here are some guesses.

To draw lines around the contours, it looks like you are currently using white (0,0,0) to outline it. -1 is to draw all contours to see if you are getting any results.

Also some cv2 functions are destructive so I never use img when I am creating the output image. I would imShow and drawContours on a copy of the original img.

```
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, GREEN, 5)
```

Comment: let me try that

Comment: this is what i got as a reult   https://photos.app.goo.gl/pLtpEHYWTirD5Yj86

Comment: this would be the desired Result. https://photos.app.goo.gl/uiYQXytQAuxPYzN4A

Comment: Your threshold probably needs to be changed, as you can see on your first picture we are drawing all detected edges but your picture does not even include the boxes you want. I usually imshow with few different ranges until I get hard edges on my point of interest. Once you have a decent threshold, you can look into cv2.RETR_TREE as different cv2 hierarches will link together contour shapes (like which ones are contained by others etc). Sometimes this is useful, sometimes not necessary.